# Trying to return class instance from class method in ruby

Tags: ruby, rest, neo4j

I'm trying to write a wrapper around the rest api for Neo4j. The other ORMs I've found don't quite do what I need them to do. I want to have something that mimics ActiveRecord, but for a graph database. So when I do somethiing like "NeoRest.find(id=1)" I want it to return the database record that corresponds to that id, but I want to return it as a NeoRest instance. My code is below. I've looked all over the web and can't find anything to help me out -- hopefully this isn't a stupid question =\

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

class NeoRest

    def NeoRest.post(key = nil, value = nil)
#       NeoRest.new

        base_url= URI('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/')

        response = Net::HTTP.post_form(base_url, {key => value})
        decode=JSON.parse(response.body)
        puts decode["self"]
        puts decode["data"]
    end #testrest
end #class

bob=NeoRest.post("name", "josh")
puts bob.class #=> nilclass -- want thiis to be =>NeoRest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby methods return result of last statement. In your case it will be `puts(...)` which returns `nil`

Probably you want code something like this:

```
class NeoRest

    def self.post(key = nil, value = nil)
        new(key, value)
    end

    def initialize(key = nil, value = nil)

        base_url= URI('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/')

        response = Net::HTTP.post_form(base_url, {key => value})
        @decode=JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is closer to what I want to do, though I think i probably want all the initialize logic inside the post method, this way i can also make self.put, self.get, etc, and then i can just make them instances of NeoRest by calling new inside them as well.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up getting what I needed. I rearranged things a little, but now, inside the .post method, I call another method, which instantiates an obejct of NeoRest, then passes the information returned from the REST method into it.

```
class NeoRest
    def self.post(key = nil, value = nil)
        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/db/data/node/")
        response = @http.request(request)
        create_instance(response)
    end

    def self.create_instance(response)
        decode=JSON.parse(response.body)
        instance = self.new 
        instance.data=decode["data"]
        puts "created following instance"
        puts instance
        instance
    end
end
```